# Drop rows containing a certain numeric pattern (int64) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

Surprisingly cannot find a simple answer.

I have two columns in a dataframe. Column1 is `int64`.

```
Column1  Column2
19970101  400
19970102  300
19980101  200
```

How to delete rows with `1997` pattern in `Column1`?  It is not a string, so regular expression would not work, I believe.

I guess I can split it into two parts and remove all rows, just having `1997` separately, and then combine again, but would be great to find a more simple solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well:

```
df[df['Column1']//10000 != 1997]
```

Or converting it to string:

```
df[df['Column1'].astype(str).str[:4] != '1997']
```

Answer (score 2):

Then convert to `str`

```
df[~df['Column1'].astype(str).str.startswith('1997')]
Out[49]: 
    Column1  Column2
2  19980101      200
```

---

When we due with datetime object we can always do `to_datetime`

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df.Column1,format='%Y%m%d').dt.year!=1997]
Out[52]: 
    Column1  Column2
2  19980101      200
```